# POST json string in NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

In my iOS app I am posting json string to server using NSURLConnection like this.

```
    post_string = @"{"function":"getHuddleDetails", "parameters": {"user_id": "167","location_id": "71","huddle_id": "328","checkin_id": "1287"},"token":""}"


  -(void)myServerRequests:(NSString *)post_string{


    NSData *postData = [post_string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myServerURl.com/jsonpost"]];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:100];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (conn) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }

   }
```

And posting **multipart/form-data** (not JSON) using NSURLSession using below code

```
 -(void)myFunction:(NSString *)user_name paswd:(NSString *)pass_word {

   NSString *boundary = [self boundaryString];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myServerURl.com/formpost"]];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];



   NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

   NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
  [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




   [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"username\"\r\n\r\n%@", user_name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n%@", pass_word] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




     NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:postbody completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSAssert(!error, @"%s: uploadTaskWithRequest error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);


      NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;



    }];
    [task resume];
  }
```

This works perfectly fine with NSURLSession, but when I tried to post json string (converted it to NSDATA and posted using NSURLSession), it is not working.

Why it happens ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to do better than "not working." Errors reported, do you get incorrect data, have you tracked what you're getting or not getting on the server?  Lots more stuff to tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send JSON to a server you should set the content type accordingly to `application/json` and your content is actually just that: the JSON encoded preferably in UTF-8.

In your method `myServerRequests:` you set content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - but you don't setup the corresponding content correctly. How to do this can be read here: [URL-encoded form data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data). Additionally, specifying a charset parameter has no effect at all.

In case you want to send a string parameter for a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, you should also not use a lossy conversion. Instead use UTF-8. Note that `NSString`s `length` returns the number of UTF-16 code points - which is not the same as the number of bytes of an UTF-8 encoded string.

**Recap:**

Don't use application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type. Instead:

`Content-Type = application/json`

`Content-Length = <length in bytes of the UTF-8 encoded JSON>`

When you fix these issues, the request should be OK.

When using a multipart/form-data request I strongly recommend to use a network library. Doing this by hand is too error prone and you would need to read at least 300 RFCs to know that you are doing it correctly ;)